# How to stop people having an mp3 play through quicktime

Tags: javascript, quicktime

I send out a http link for an mp3 to people and when they click on it they are complaining that the file plays in quictime. Obviously they need to do 'right click' --> 'save target as' but is there a way to do this for them using javascript?

Comment: You can try to do that with any server side plugin/script that allows you to modify the header. But you cannot force a download via JavaScript. Also I'm afraid that QuickTime will always attempt to play a file from in the browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't be done using JavaScript. But there are many ways to do that using server side scripts. I only know classic asp: Response.AddHeader "content-disposition","attachment; filename=fname.ext"

Comment: Yep this is what I was looking for Quicktime will not play it will just get a download option...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have PHP?
http://elouai.com/force-download.php